# Comma, period to separate sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, commas, periods

Let's say somebody fell from a tree. Now consider the following sentence.

- His face become full dirt, a tooth has broken, muscles bleed, arm bone broken and his dress has torn.
- His face become full dirt. A tooth has broken. Muscles bleed. Arm bones broken and his dress has torn.

Which one is correct in situation like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with some sentences:

> S1. S2. S3. S4. S5.

We can combine them with *and*, with or without commas:

> S1 and S2 and S3 and S4 and S5.
>   S1, and S2, and S3, and S4, and S5.

We can optionally delete every *and* except the last one.
Although it's optional,  we do it most of the time:

> S1, S2, S3, S4, and S5.

When we do this, most of the commas are required.
(The last one is optional.)

---

Now let's look at your sentences:

> S1 = His face become full dirt.
>   S2 = A tooth has broken.
>   S3 = Muscles bleed.
>   S4 = Arm bones broken.
>   S5 = His dress has torn.

These sentences have various problems.  In particular, S1 is ungrammatical, S2 would normally have the possessor of the tooth as its subject, S3 sounds like a generalization about muscles, S4 isn't a complete sentence, S5 uses *dress* to refer to what is probably not a dress, and the sentences don't mesh in tense or aspect. We need to fix these things before we even *think* about combining them.

Let's try these five sentences instead:

> S1 = His face was full of dirt.
>   S2 = He'd broken a tooth.
>   S3 = His muscles were bleeding.
>   S4 = His arms were broken.
>   S5 = His clothes were torn.

Now we can **optionally** combine them:

> His face was full of dirt
>   **and** he'd broken a tooth
>   **and** his muscles were bleeding
>   **and** his arms were broken
>   **and** his clothes were torn.

Usually we delete every *and* except the last one and insert commas:

> His face was full of dirt,
>   he'd broken a tooth,
>   his muscles were bleeding,
>   his arms were broken,
>   **and** his clothes were torn.

Now we've combined them successfully.  But we don't need to.  We could just put one sentence after another:

> His face was full of dirt.
>   He'd broken a tooth.
>   His muscles were bleeding.
>   His arms were broken.
>   His clothes were torn.

Which should you do?  Whichever you like.  It's grammatical either way.